# Log and monitor network usage by session/connection

Tags: windows, logging, network-monitoring

In Resource Monitor, Network tab, in the Network Activity section, I can see each active session and how much bandwidth it is using.

I'd like to capture that information over a period of time, is there a way via a Microsoft tool or a third-party?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps). Use this cmdlet to view TCP connection properties such as local or remote IP address, local or remote port, and connection state.

Use this for example to list

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Established
```